# Запрос SELECT к SQLite ничего не возвращает

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, sqlite

Решил я прикрутить к своему проекту файловую базу данных. Ну и выбрал как самый простой вариант - sqlite. Базу данных заранее создал, открыл, вставил туда пару строк SQL-запросами - все нормально. При попытке сделать выборку из БД - ловлю ошибку, а точнее запрос выполняется но размер QSqlQuery равен -1. Не могу понять в чем проблема, если кто сталкивался - подскажите что делать.

Тестовая база данных: testt.db - файл БД собственно, с одной таблицей testTable с 4 строками и 2 столбцами (id и data, где id - уникальный столбец и первичный ключ)

Привожу кусок кода с тестовой базой данных (думал что проблема в сложной архитектуре но нет)

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("CommonData\\databases\\testt.db");
db.open();
qDebug() << db.isOpen();
QSqlQuery selectQuery = QSqlQuery(db);

qDebug() << "Query status: " << selectQuery.exec("SELECT * FROM testTable");
qDebug() << "Query size: " << selectQuery.size();
qDebug() << selectQuery.value(0).toString();
```

Вывод консоли отладки:

```
true
true
-1
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

Comment: [next()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-sqlstatements.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, так работает. Можете еще помочь? Как мне проверить результат выборки на пустоту? Я конечно могу в цикле прогнать и чекнуть после счетчик но кажется это костыльно, может есть способ попроще? А то size по-прежнему -1

Comment: @CreateStudio А почему это костыльно? Если есть записи - прогоняете и обрабатываете, а если нет - то и прогонять долго не придется.